# Trouble installing Boost and Boost-cpp in anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, boost, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to install some packages that have dependencies on either boost 1.63 or boost-cpp 1.66. I am installing via conda install and I am working in an anaconda virtual environment that has python 3.6 and anaconda 4.2.13.

When I try to install my packages it gets stuck when "extracting files" from boost 1.63 or boost 1.66. It doesn't error out, it just gets stuck and doesn't finish extracting (waited on 25% for over half an hour my most recent attempt).

Is there anything I can do about this?

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing `Ctrl+C`. I got this same error on when I was trying to `install gdal`, when the installation got to boost-cpp, it got stuck. I pressed `Ctrl+C` thinking I would quit and try again, but then the installation started continuing again after `Ctrl+C`.